# How to specify a sample for a response representation of a Microsoft Azure API operation using Terraform azurerm

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-api-management, azure-rm

I am using Terraform to specify an operation on an Azure API within API Management.  The functionality of the operation is simple right now:  no matter what is passed in, just mock the same response.  Manually, this is simple.  You just edit the front end of the operation, click the Responses tab, select a response, add a representation, and specify the return in the Sample field.  Then, you just have to specify a  inbound policy and choose that specific response.  Done.

Doing the same thing in Terraform is not proving to be as easy.  The only part that is missing is the Sample field that defines what is returned.  I have tried following the documentation here:  https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/api_management_api_operation.

Here is my code:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "~> 2.98.0"
    }
  }

  required_version = ">= 1.1.0"
}

provider "azurerm" {
  features {
    api_management {
      purge_soft_delete_on_destroy = true
    }
  }
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "matt_test" {
  name     = "matt_test"
  location = "westus2"
}

resource "azurerm_api_management" "matts-apim" {
  name                = "matts-apim"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.matt_test.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.matt_test.name
  publisher_name      = "Publisher"
  publisher_email     = "my.email@email.com"
  sku_name            = "Consumption_0"
}


resource "azurerm_api_management_api" "carto-replacement-api" {
  name                = "carto-replacement-api"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.matt_test.name
  api_management_name = azurerm_api_management.matts-apim.name
  revision            = "1"
  display_name        = "CARTO Replacement"
  path                = "carto"
  protocols           = ["https"]
}

locals {
  request_example_value = {
    property = "value"
  }
  response_example_value = {
    response = "response value"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_api_management_api_operation" "bbox" {
  operation_id        = "bbox"
  api_name            = azurerm_api_management_api.carto-replacement-api.name
  api_management_name = azurerm_api_management_api.carto-replacement-api.api_management_name
  resource_group_name = azurerm_api_management_api.carto-replacement-api.resource_group_name
  display_name        = "Bounding Box"
  method              = "POST"
  url_template        = "/bbox"

  request {
    description = ""

    header {
      name     = "Content-Type"
      required = "false"
      type     = "string"
      values   = ["application/json"]
    }

    header {
      name     = "Authorization"
      required = "true"
      type     = "string"
    }

    representation {
      content_type = "application/json"
      example {
        name = "cirrus 10m terrain response"
        value = jsonencode(local.request_example_value)
      }
    }
  }

  response {
    status_code = 200
  }

  response {
    status_code = 201

    representation {
      content_type = "application/json"
      example {
        name  = "Cirrus 10m Terrain Response"
        value = jsonencode(local.response_example_value)
      }
    }
  }
}

resource "azurerm_api_management_api_operation_policy" "bbox_inbound_policy" {
  api_name            = azurerm_api_management_api_operation.bbox.api_name
  api_management_name = azurerm_api_management_api_operation.bbox.api_management_name
  resource_group_name = azurerm_api_management_api_operation.bbox.resource_group_name
  operation_id        = azurerm_api_management_api_operation.bbox.operation_id

  xml_content = <<XML
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
        <mock-response status-code="201" content-type="application/json" />
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <base />
    </backend>
    <outbound>
        <base />
    </outbound>
    <on-error>
        <base />
    </on-error>
</policies> 
    XML
}
```

Please note my attempt to provide an example for both the request and the response here.  In both cases, the Representation appears in Azure Portal, but the Sample field remains empty.  I can't figure out how to specify that in Terraform.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

For a reference, this is what it looks in the Azure Portal UI:
[image]

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this issue? I run into the same thing.

Comment: Sadly, no.  I ended up adding them by hand if I really felt they were needed or I just left them blank.  :(

Answer (score 4):

I got the same problem, and naming example's name "default" sovled it.

```
  response {
    status_code = 200
    description = "200"
    representation {
      content_type = "application/json"
      example {
        name = "default"
        value = jsonencode({
          response = "ok"
        })
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Hmmm...I'm going to have to try that.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the issue, one thing that is recommended in Terraform is not to use heredoc syntax to generate YAML or JSON [1]. Having said that, I would try with:

```
value = jsonencode({
 property = "value"
})
```

and for the response:

```
value = jsonencode({
  response = "response value"
})
```

What might be the best combination is to use the variables and `jsonenode` built-in function, e.g.:

```
locals {
  request_example = {
    property = "value"
  }

  response_example = {
    response = "response value"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_api_management_api_operation" "bbox" {
.
.
.
  request {
    .
    .
    .
    representation {
      content_type = "application/json"
      example {
        name = "cirrus 10m terrain response"
        value = jsonencode(local.request_example) # <------
      }
    }
  }

  response {
    status_code = 200
    description = "HTTP 200 response" # Required!
  }

  response {
    status_code = 201
    description = "HTTP 201 response" # Required!

    representation {
      content_type = "application/json"
      example {
        name  = "Cirrus 10m Terrain Response"
        value = jsonencode(local.response_example) # <-----
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This way you can edit the request and response examples without worrying if that will have to be updated in more places.

---

[1] https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/strings#generating-json-or-yaml

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I am new to terraform (obviously).  I have updated my example with your suggestion to follow better practice.  Unfortunately, this update did not address the actual issue I'm seeing.  The example is still empty when I look at the API in Azure Portal.

Comment: Can you just try for the sake of it setting `sample` instead of `example` with the same values?

Comment: That's a good thought and actually is the first thing I tried when it didn't work.  `sample` has been deprecated in favor of `example` but I thought, what the heck, may as well try it.  Still no luck.  :(

Comment: And how about `examples` instead of `example`?

Comment: I think I know what the problem is, I edited the question. The `description` is required for the response as well: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/api_management_api_operation#:~:text=description%20%2D%20(Required)%20A%20description%20of%20the%20HTTP%20Response%2C%20which%20may%20include%20HTML%20tags.

Comment: The note in the docs says `examples` but the rest of the docs say `example` and when I tried the former, I got errors from terraform that that particular keyword is not supported.

Comment: As for the issue being that `description` is required for the response, I know the docs say that, but it doesn't actually seem to matter.  I tried with a description and it didn't do anything other than populate the description field.  It didn't affect whether or not the example was shown in the Portal Sample field, which was still empty.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue, I had configured the response example but not actually returning anything.

The problem for my scenario was using a **custom name** for the example. When I switched to "**default**" it worked.

NOT WORKING:

```
 representation {
  content_type = "application/json"
  example {
    name = "animals"
    value = jsonencode(
     {
       id: 1,
       name: "dog"
     }
    )
  }
```

WORKING:

```
representation {
  content_type = "application/json"
  example {
    name = "default"
    value = jsonencode(
     {
       id: 1,
       name: "dog"
     }
    )
  }
```